# Mysql Neo4j full synchronization

Tags: mysql, neo4j, neo4jclient, neo4j-ogm

I have data stored in my `Mysql`. I find ways in which I can load my `My-SQL` data in Neo4j.

What I am looking for is I want my data to reflect in `Neo4j` if it has got updated in `Mysql`. Also if there are any new entries in `Mysql`, it should reflect it in `Neo4j`.

I.e Can I integrate `Mysql` and `neo4j` and achieve full synchronization?

Comment: Do you have any CDC process running against mysql? If not, batch loading is the best you'll get

Comment: no, I do not have any CDC process.